# Relationship Between Mongodb and Mysql databases

Tags: laravel-5

I am Trying to get data from mysql and mongodb in laravel framework.I am using  HybridRelations to fetch data realated data but I stuck.please help me.

I got Error like that.

> Call to undefined relationship [Country] on model [App\Models\State].

Here is my code. 
              country model;

```
namespace App;
namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Country extends Eloquent
{

 protected $connection = 'mongodb';

 protected $collection = 'countries';

 protected $fillable = [ 'country' ];


 public function country()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(State::class,'country_id');

 }
}
```

my state model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class State extends Model
{

    use HybridRelations;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $table = 'state';
    protected $primaryKey = 'state_id';

    protected $fillable = [  'name','code','status' ];

    public function state()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, '_id');
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the code you're using to call the relationship?

Comment: @fez    public function country()
            {
                   $State =  State::with('Country')->get();


                   return view('country', ['viewdata' => $State]);

            }